# Match + operator in string except when it is in quotes?

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I want to match + except when it is between double quotes. Meaning i want "anystring"+
to give me true result but "\D+","anystring" to return me false.

Right now i am using /\".*\s*\"\s*+/|/+\s*\".*\s*\"/ regex but it is not giving me correct result. Regex needed to used in groovy language.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem with this kind of match is that you could have inputs like `"anystring"+"anystring"`. Would you consider the `+` to be between quotes or not? Probably not, but it's almost impossible for a regex pattern to make that assessment.

Comment: So you are saying there is no way to do that in regex?

Comment: Try this regex: \+\s*(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)

Comment: @pradyumn Yes, I don't think there's a foolproof way. Maybe someone else could come up with a regex but it would be very complicated. I would say regex isn't the right tool for this.